# Which version of m4 does the author of Debugging with GDB use?

Tags: gdb

I am trying to learn how to debug programs with gdb following [Debugging with GDB](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Sample-Session.html#Sample-Session).The first chapter of this book present a sample seesion to debug programs.My question is where could I get this buggy verion of m4?I want to redo this sample debug seession.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug was likely injected into `m4` on purpose (just to demonstrate `GDB`). I doubt there was ever an official release of GNU `m4` which actually had this bug.

You can download any version of `m4`, change

```
len_lquote = strlen(lquote);
```

to

```
len_lquote = strlen(rquote);
```

in `set_quotes()`, and then redo the sample debugging session.

However, I see very little point in actually doing that. Your time would probably be spent more wisely if instead you select any open-source program you like and use, and try to find/fix a real open bug in it.

P.S. The online docs you referred to have moved [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Sample-Session.html#Sample-Session).